# How can I avoid creating useless pass-through constructors in child classes just to pass arguments to "super()"?

Tags: java, parameters, constructor, parameter-passing, subclass

In Java, as far as I'm aware, a child class ***does NOT*** inherit a constructor that has arguments.

E.g.

```
public class Parent {
    public Parent(int x) {
        DoSomethingWithX(x);
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    // Compile fails with "Implicit super constructor Parent() is undefined 
    // for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor
}
```

The only way to fix it is to create a useless pass-through constructor in Child class:

```
public class Child extends Parent {
    public Child(int x) {
         super(x);
    }
}
```

## Problem:

If I have a complex hierarchy of subclasses, with 6-10 subclasses, adding such a meaningless pass-through constructor with arguments **to every single one of subclasses** seems to be a bad idea!

- The code plain out looks stupid (10 copies of same method in 10 classes)
- Worse, as with ANY code repetition, the code becomes fragile - any change (e.g. adding 1 more parameter) needs to be made in 10 places instead of one.

## Question:

Is there a way to avoid this issue for a large class hierarchy?

## Note:

I'm aware of one solution (have a setter, that has to be called separate from constructor) for the parameters. But this solution has several big downsides and isn't acceptable because of them.

Comment: Maybe your design is the problem? Why do you have such a huge hierarchy? You can't avoid having a constructor. Maybe you should be using interfaces or abstract classes.

Comment: @Zar - how would either interfaces or abstract classes help me with the problem I described?

Comment: I mean see if it's possible to restructure your program using interfaces or abstract classes to reduce the size of this hierarchy.

Comment: @Zar - Impossible. In general, I would recommend *not* assuming that every SO question is an X-Y problem

Comment: At first glance, I have my doubts related to the design, but let's assume you can't do anything about it ... what if your constructors receive a Map, or a CustomClass class that contains every parameter you could possible need.
That way if you need to change parameters and arguments you can only change the class you are interested about.

Comment: "But this solution has several big downsides and isn't acceptable because of them" What are these downsides?

Comment: Short answer: no.  Long answer: nooooo.

Comment: @psabbate - yep. at the moment what you suggest seems to be the LEAST bad solution :)

Comment: I half-agree with Zar.  Your design likely needs to be re-thought.  Use inheritance only when you must, not whenever you can.  A good test is:  If you aren’t using polymorphism, your use of inheritance is inappropriate.  (You’re using polymorphism if code outside the inheritance hierarchy actually refers to the parent classes.  Inheritance should never be just a way to share data or functionality.)

Comment: @VGR - unfortunately for you and Zar, i AM using polymorphysm. I've been using OOP for a better part of 20 years, thankyouverymuch, and know how to design classes (just not Java specifics of implementing the design in a way that appeals to me).

Comment: Can you use a setter instead? If not (briefly) why not? Immutability? Some kind of special initialization?

Comment: @Bohemian - 2 reasons: (1) tons of constructor calls (which means the code is more fragile - need to remember to call the setter as a separate call every place a constructor is called); (2) Code was designed to run init logic in the constructor, which requires parameters being set (yes, I know it's a bad design. Not my option to fix it)

Comment: @DVK Not your option to fix it? Then who's is it? See my answer for the standard solution to this problem, still guaranteeing initialization but just rearranging it.

Comment: @Bohemian - Someone who has free time and no deliverables to complete would be a good candidate to rewrite the entire codebase :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like 15 years ago I had a similar problem to yours with a very broad (but only slightly deep) hierarchy (and yes, folks, there was a *reason* it was the way it was). But since they all derived from a base that we periodically needed to add more information to, it was quickly apparent that adding parameters to the base constructor was prohibitively painful.

Not inheriting constructors by default is a good thing, but sometimes you *want* to inherit them. I've sometimes wanted a compile-time annotation I could add to a class to tell the compiler "auto-generate constructors for any of super's constructors I don't explicitly implement". But we don't have it, and a JSR would take years to go through if it were successful at all...

Not having that magic annotation, the solution we used was exactly the one @psabbate [mentioned in his/her comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39732984/how-can-i-avoid-creating-useless-pass-through-constructors-in-child-classes-just#comment66764017_39732984):

> what if your constructors receive a Map, or a CustomClass class that contains every parameter you could possible need. That way if you need to change parameters and arguments you can only change the class you are interested about.

...but with a specific type hierarchy for the parameters classes (not `Map`).

For completeness, an example:

```
// The standard parameters needed
class StandardParams {
    private String thisArg;

    public StandardParams(String thisArg) {
        this.thisArg = thisArg;
    }

    public String getThisArg() {
        return this.thisArg;
    }
}

// The base class
class Base {
    public Base(StandardParams args) {
        System.out.println("Base: " + args.getThisArg());
    }
}

// A standard subclass
class Sub1 extends Base {
    public Sub1(StandardParams args) {
        super(args);
        System.out.println("Sub1 thisArg: " + args.getThisArg());
    }
}
```

To me it's not even "least bad." Having a type that represents the base information that the hierarchy needs is expressive.

If a subclass needs more information than the standard parameters (which came up for us), you have the option of a second parameters class type that you use as a second parameter (but then you have two types of constructors in the tree) or using inheritance in the parameters class hierarchy; we used the latter:

```
// Extended parameters (naturally you make these names meaningful)
class ExtendedParams extends StandardParams {
    private String thatArg;

    public ExtendedParams(String thisArg, String thatArg) {
        super(thisArg);
        this.thatArg = thatArg;
    }

    public String getThatArg() {
        return this.thatArg;
    }
}

// A subclass requiring extended parameter information
class Sub2 extends Base {
    public Sub2(ExtendedParams args) {
        super(args);
        System.out.println("Sub2 thisArg: " + args.getThisArg());
        System.out.println("Sub2 thatArg: " + args.getThatArg());
    }
}
```

In my case IIRC, we only had three parameters classes (the standard one and two subs for particular branches in the tree) across something like 30 main classes in the hierarchy.

A final note: For us, there was a core set of things we needed to provide to the parameters class when constructing it which didn't vary and there were something like eight options that had reasonable, basic defaults but you could override. To avoid an explosion of constructors in the parameter classes, we ended up doing a bit of a poor man's builder pattern on them ("poor man's" because we made the classes their own builders rather than separating it out; it just wasn't necessary to be *that* rigorous about it, the things that changed had inexpensive defaults and so the instance was always in a valid state even when being built). So construction for us looked something like this:

```
Thingy t = new Thingy(
    new ThingyParams(basic, construction, info)
    .withAnswer(42)
    .withQuestion("Life, the Universe, and Everything")
);
```

Comment: This is *exactly* what I ended up doing yesterday. Not sure why you marked as CW :)

Comment: @DVK: :-) Just for the avoidance of any appearance of impropriety, as psabbate had mentioned virtually the same thing in a comment.

Answer (score 4):

Use a factory method and reflection:

```
public class A {
    protected A() {
        // No longer do initialization in constructor
        // initialize in init(), which is guaranteed to be called
    }

    protected A init(int i) {
        // do all initialization with i in here
        return this;
    };

    public static <T extends A> T create(Class<T> clazz, int i) {
        try {
            return (T) clazz.newInstance().init(i);
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("not going to happen", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Creating the instance is then:

```
B b = A.create(B.class, 86);
```

Depending on the discipline level you want, sub-classes can either be as simple as:

```
public class B extends A {
    // nothing special needed
}
```

but allows direct instantiation `B b = new B()` not requiring the `int`, or you can tighten everything up to prevent that like this:

```
public class B extends A {
    protected B() {
        super();
    }
    // nothing else special needed
}
```

which requires all instantiation to go via the factory method.

Changing your code at the call points can be easily refactored using your IDE.

If your base class changes to require more/different initializing variables, you only have to change the factory method (nothing changes in the sub classes), or you can add a new factory method, keeping the old one for backward compatibility.

Comment: Perfect! I actually tried this solution (it was my favorite one) before settling on @T.J. Crowder's one, but couldn't get the generics figured out fast enough when writing the builder. +1, excellent approach.

Comment: @dvk np. You know you can always change which answer is accepted. Just click a different answer's accept tick thingy

Comment: This is one rare case where I wish I could accept two. I might throw a bounty your way though if I don't forget

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you have only a constructor on `Parent` that takes an argument tells me that you cannot create a `Parent` without said int.  And by creating a `Child`, you are, by means of inheritance, also creating a `Parent`.  And because we need an int to create the `Parent`, the `Child` has to provide it from somewhere, be it either from its own constructor argument or some other static value.

If you don't want to provide a pass-through constructor in every subclass of your `Parent`, you need to provide a no-arg constructor on it and define what that means.  This can be in addition to the constructor you already have or replace it, that's up to you.  But the no-arg constructor is necessary for you to do what you want to do.